# When to pass a pointer and when to pass the memory address of a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, root-framework

I am looking at the following piece of code:

```
  StJetEvent* jets = 0;
  jetChain->SetBranchAddress("AntiKtR060NHits12",&jets);
```

Where we have that:
The class of `jetChain` is `TChain`
and the definition of `SetBranchAddress` is:

```
Int_t TChain::SetBranchAddress  (   const char *    bname, void *   add, TBranch **     ptr = 0)
```

The definition of the relevant parameters inside of the the argument of the `SetBranchAddress` is:

bname   is the name of a branch.
add is the address of the branch.

For some reason, when I look at `SetBranchAddress("AntiKtR060NHits12",&jets)`, based on the definition of the function `SetBranchAddress`, I would think that the second parameter that needs to be passed is a pointer, but instead the address of the pointer `jets` is passed. This is consistent with what the definition of what the second parameter is, but from my basic understanding, I thought that `void *    add` means to pass a pointer and NOT the address of the pointer.

Can someone please provide me with some clarification, please? Thank you very much!

Comment: The pointer of my pointer is a pointer. Keep your pointers close and your enemies... pointier?

Comment: You do know that a "pointer" is nothing special, it is just a variable, like any other, that holds the address of something else (the thing it points to). Right?

Comment: you need to know what it expects and what it's going to do with it, so "it depends" -- although the correct answer in modern practice is "neither"

Comment: Anyway if you just sent `jets`, which is a `nullptr` here, you couldn't do anything with it. If you pass a pointer to `jets`, you can modify it. It's passing by pointer. So `SetBranchAddress` looks like it is responsible for allocating memory for `jets` and returning the memory location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `&z` returns a pointer to `z`. The terms "address of X" and "pointer to X" mean almost exactly the same thing.

```
int z;
int* q = &z; // now q is a pointer to z
int** r = &q;
```

When we say "q is a pointer to z", we mean two things:

1. The type of 'q' is pointer to whatever type 'z' is.
2. The value of 'q' is the address of 'z'.

So here, 'r' is a pointer to 'q' for the same reasons.